# pdf not downloading when button is pressed

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation

I copied the example off of the syncfusion_flutter_pdf pub dev but when I press the button to download or save pdf nothing happens and it doesn't show any error.

Here is the code:

---

```
onPressed: () async {
// Create a new PDF document.
final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
// Add a new page to the document.
final PdfPage page = document.pages.add();
// Create a PDF grid class to add tables.
final PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
// Specify the grid column count.
grid.columns.add(count: 3);
// Add a grid header row.
final PdfGridRow headerRow = grid.headers.add(1)[0];
headerRow.cells[0].value = 'Customer ID';
headerRow.cells[1].value = 'Contact Name';
headerRow.cells[2].value = 'Country';
// Set header font.
headerRow.style.font =
    PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 10, style: PdfFontStyle.bold);
// Add rows to the grid.
PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
row.cells[0].value = 'ALFKI';
row.cells[1].value = 'Maria Anders';
row.cells[2].value = 'Germany';
// Add next row.
row = grid.rows.add();
row.cells[0].value = 'ANATR';
row.cells[1].value = 'Ana Trujillo';
row.cells[2].value = 'Mexico';
// Add next row.
row = grid.rows.add();
row.cells[0].value = 'ANTON';
row.cells[1].value = 'Antonio Mereno';
row.cells[2].value = 'Mexico';
// Set grid format.
grid.style.cellPadding = PdfPaddings(left: 5, top: 5);
// Draw table in the PDF page.
grid.draw(
    page: page,
    bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(
        0, 0, page.getClientSize().width, page.getClientSize().height));
// Save the document.
File('PDFTable.pdf').writeAsBytes(await document.save());
// Dispose the document.
document.dispose();
}
```